# recreating surfaceview on activity restart

Tags: android, surfaceview

Sorry for noob question I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong.

I have an activity which uses SurfaceView to play some content from a MediaDecoder. It all works fine on the first run, but not on the second. So if the user starts the activity, it displays correctly, than the user leaves the activity (but not the app), but when it returns to the activity in discussion I cannot get the Mediacodec to play again.

Here is what I have:

```
//LifeCycle Function
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d("HU-SERVICE","Prevent onDestroy being called due to orientation and other changes....");
    }
    @Override
    protected  void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d("HU-SERVICE","Player on Restart");
    }
    @Override
    protected  void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("HU-SERVICE","Player on Stop");
    }
    @Override
    protected  void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy ();
        Log.d("HU-SERVICE","Player on Destory");
    }
    @Override
    protected  void onPause(){
        super.onPause ();
        m_codec.flush();
        Log.d("HU-SERVICE","Player on Pause");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        getWindow ().addFlags (android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
         mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener (new View.OnTouchListener () {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
                touch_send (event);
                return (true);
            }
        });

    }
//SurfaceView
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format_2, int width, int height) {

        if (m_codec != null) {    //Clear previos codec, should not happen!
            m_codec.stop();
            m_codec=null;
        }

            Log.d("HU-SERVICE","Setting up media player");
     if (!PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("stretch_full",true))
            {

                float aspect_ratio=(float)1.66;
                if (m_virt_vid_wid!=800f)
                    aspect_ratio=(float)1.77;
                height=(int) (width/aspect_ratio);
                mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height, 17));
            }

            try {
                if (! PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("h264",false))
                { m_codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType ("video/avc");       // Create video codec
                    Log.d("HU-SERVICE","Using Hardware decoing");
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("HU-SERVICE","Using Software decoing");
                    m_codec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName("OMX.google.h264.decoder");       // Use Google OMX (software) deocding.
                    h264_wait=10000;
                    }
                }
                catch (Throwable t) {
                    hu_uti.loge ("Throwable creating video/avc decoder: " + t);
                }
            try {
                m_codec_buf_info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();                       
                MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat ("video/avc", width, height);
                m_codec.configure (format, holder.getSurface(), null, 0);              
                m_codec.start ();                                           
                }
                catch (Throwable t) {
                    hu_uti.loge ("Throwable: " + t);
                }

            }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        holder.removeCallback(this);
    holder.getSurface().release();

    }
```

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ll_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#000000">

            <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
```

This are my variables (none of them are static)

```
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private double m_virt_vid_wid=800f;
private double m_virt_vid_hei=480f;
private PowerManager m_pwr_mgr;
private PowerManager.WakeLock m_wakelock;
private MediaCodec m_codec;
private MediaCodec.BufferInfo m_codec_buf_info;
private int h264_wait;
```

On the first run of the activity I have audio+video on the second run I hear the audio but the screen is pure black, what I'm missing?

**EDIT**

I did a bit of digging and I found that on the second run of the activity after a relatively short period of time actually I see the following error:

```
E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
E/ACodec: queueBuffer failed in onOutputBufferDrained: -19
E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -19)
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xffffffed, actionCode 0, while in state 6
```

It's like MediaCode tries to output to a different Surface somehow... 
I'm really lost, couldn't find anything which would explain this behaviour...